# set location of dll class library which is referenced in other project in solution

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, dll

I'm doing a solution which has a 3 projects(c#).

1. Main executable project
2. Dll
3. Dll

Main project has references to others.
I want to have following file structure in my main project:

```
main.exe 
Libraries - folder
  + 2.dll
  + 3.dll
```

But unfortunately VS is putting those DLL files to EXE location.

It there any simple solution to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the Output Path on the child DLLs to point to Libraries.

However, this is not a standard path that .Net probes at runtime for DLL resolution, so you will likely have issues when you try to deploy this unless you load from these locations by hand.

If you have the project reference marked to Copy Local, then I don't believe that you can change the directory that Visual Studio copies files into through configuration.

However, you could setup a post-build command that automatically moves the files into the desired subdirectory after each build.

**Update**

I love this site because it enables me to learn new things every day. As a case in point, I just discovered the [probing element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/823z9h8w%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) that you can add to your config file in order to add additional paths to the standard probing paths.

This configuration element allow .Net to search your `libraries` folder for DLLs to load so that you don't have to do any additional work once they are in place (you will still need to move them to that directory using a postbuild command).

Here is a sample config entry to support your configuration:

```
<configuration>
   <runtime>
      <assemblyBinding>
         <probing privatePath="bin\libraries"/>
      </assemblyBinding>
   </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Yes I know it but I dont want to change this path which you mean. There are two copies of those dll files. They are in their project directory and VS is doing also compies of them in the main project which location I want to change...

Comment: @nosbor - Why? The correct location is with the application itself. The only reason you have 2 copies is because of Visual Studio. If you were to setup an installer solution, and installed your program, you would have a single copy of each. As pointed out, what you want is not standard behavior, which means you would have to load the files BY HAND and NOT us visual studio to reference them.  The only reason you have two copies is being your building your solution on the same computer.  The reasony you want to change this are just silly.

Comment: No its normal behavior and Vs i loading it normally right now. Look... every od dll project have their dll compiled assembly in their own /bin/Debug directory and in addition VS is copying those assemblies to the main project /bin/Debug folder. And I want to change it to /bin/Debug/Libraries

Comment: I am pretty sure that you cannot change the behavior of visual studio; I believe that your only built-in choice is to have the DLLs copied to bin\debug. However, you can add a post-build command that will then move your DLLs from the bin\debug folder to the bin\debug\libraries folder. We use this method all the time for moving files around after projects are built.

Comment: @competent_tech But then I will need to load the dll library manualy, yes?

Comment: @nosbor: I thought that you would have to load the files manually, but I just discovered how you can tell .net where to look. See the updated answer for details.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue, but previous examples doesn't worked. Only after i pointed the scheme, everything worked fine:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <probing privatePath="Libraries"/>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Comment: +1 I wish I had found this sooner as I was finding none of the `assemblyBinding` provisions would work for me.